# Stubbing time in a Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, stubbing

I have a page that creates a snapshot of a document. That document is saved with the title being a timestamp (`September 27, 2014 at 4:01:10 pm`) for example. I am writing a test for this page and want to stub time so that it doesn't change.

What I have at the moment is `Time.stubs(:now).returns(Time.parse("2014-1-2 11:00:00"))` but when I do that I get an error message saying:

> Capybara::FrozenInTime: time appears to be frozen, Capybara does not work with libraries which freeze time, consider using time travelling instead

What is the best way to stub out time here?

Comment: You might want to check out the `timecop` gem: https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Comment: @sjaime if you will post that as an answer, I will select it. That is super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reposting here my comment as an answer.

There is the `timecop` gem https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

It allows you to do things like the following:

```
describe "some set of tests to mock" do
  before do
    Timecop.freeze(Time.local(1990))
  end

  after do
    Timecop.return
  end

 it "should do blah blah blah" {}
end
```

which will make the tests run as if it was 1990-1-1 and then return back to the current time.

Answer (score 3):

Rails now [includes support](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/TimeHelpers.html) for time travel directly, e.g.:

```
feature 'Time travel verifier' do
  include ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelpers

  scenario 'works in the past' do
    travel_to(1.day.ago) do
      visit time_travel_verification_path
      expect(page).to have_content('WOAH Time Travel!')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is much more idiomatic solution to time travelling in specs